# How to create unique constrain on a field using ruby mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Hi I want to create a unique constrain on a field I'm using `Ruby on Rails` version 5 with `mongodb` I'm using `mongoid`

```
 class SkillSet
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :name, type: String # this field has to be unique

   def some_method
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create index [mongoid-index](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-indexes/) on that field below is the updated code

```
class SkillSet
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String 
  index({ name: 1 }, { unique: true, name: "name_index" })


  def some_method
  end
end
```

run this `rake db:mongoid:create_indexes` to create index in mongodb